# Is it true that $\coprod_{x\in A}\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R\times A$?

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering if when $A\subset \mathbb R$, does $\coprod_{x\in A}\mathbb R$ is homoemorphic to $A\times \mathbb R$ ? Actually, they enven look equal, no ?

I think it is. Let $\phi: A\times \mathbb R\to \coprod_{x\in A}$ defined by $\varphi (a,x)=(a,x)$. Of course it's a bijection. Let $(A\cap U)\times V$ where $U,V$ are open in $\mathbb R$. Then $\Phi^{-1}(A\cap U\times V)=A\cap U\times V$ which is open in $A\times \mathbb R$. The fact that $\phi$ is open is proved in the same way.

Is it correct ?

Comment: Are you sure you mean the copproduct of $|A|$ many copies of $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a natural bijection between the two sets, but there isn't necessarily a homeomorphism between them.

Consider $A = \Bbb R$. Then $\coprod_{x\in \Bbb R}\Bbb R$ is a disconnected collection of lines, while $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ is a connected plane.

The two spaces are homeomorphic (and the natural bjection is a homeomorphism) iff $A$ is discrete.

Comment: Good point ! Thank you very much. Is it easy to prove that $\coprod_{x\in\mathbb R}$ is totally disconected ? or we just "see it" ?

Comment: @user657324 It's not totally disconnected, as each line is still a copy of $\Bbb R$ and as such connected. But yes, it is easy to see that each line is clopen. That's basically by definition of the coproduct / disjoint union.

Comment: what do you mean by totally disconnected ? is it that each singleton are open ?

Comment: @user657324 You were the one who said "totally disconnected", I thought you knew what it meant. And no, it's not _quite_ the same as discrete. It means that for any two distinct points you can find disjoint, clopen neighbourhoods around each point (basically the same as the Hausdorff criterion, only with clopen instead of open). For instance, $\Bbb Q$ with the standard topology is totally disconnected, but not discrete.